# inset box-shadow for inputfield

Tags: css

Can an inset box-shadow work on an inputfield?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hKTq2/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, this is something I was working on the other day, it is indeed possible.

```
input
{
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
  background: #fff;
}
```

You just need to have a background set for the shadow to fall onto :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/ZCq6w/

Answer (score 11):

In the meantime, this has become a common, though here's my "the perfect inset input".

```css
input {
  background: #fff;
  color: #525865;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.45;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.6em 1.45em 0.7em;
  -webkit-transition: .18s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .18s ease-out;
  -o-transition: .18s ease-out;
  transition: .18s ease-out;
}
input:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
input:focus {
  color: #4b515d;
  border: 1px solid #B8B6B6;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
body {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add :

```
background-color:transparent;
```

Comment: not really. you can use whatever color based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Hi ADD this css then you able to insert shadow

```
.innershadow{ -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #888; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px#888; box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #888; height:15px; background-color:transparent; height:50px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `background:none;` on class `.innershadow`

http://jsfiddle.net/jack_fiddle/hKTq2/6/

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this to realize a inset dropshadow inside the text-input:

```
.innershadow {  
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #999;
    padding: 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 5px #888;
    box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 5px #888;
    border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;
}
```

HTH,

--hennson